# Tengo una duda con el bucle for

Tags: java

resulta que estaba haciendo el factorial de un número con el bucle for y no comprendo algo por más que lo intento.
código fuente:

```
int factorial=1, numero, i;
        numero = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("digite el numero: "));
        for(i=1;i<=numero;i++ ){
            factorial *= i;
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El factorial es: "+factorial);
```

NO comprendo cómo en la variable factorial se obtiene el resultado sin tocar la variable que se extrae el dato, no comprendo como el número que doy, ejemplo, 3, este haga la operacion 3x2x1 sin tocar dentro del bucle a esta variable, les agradezco

Comment: La variable si se "toca", está en la condición del for. En programación hay muchas formas de hacer lo mismo. Ya sea modificando la variable original, una copia o no.

Answer (score 2):

1-la variable factorial tendrá el valor que se le asigne ya sea `factorial=1` o `factorial=100`,etc..

2-`factorial *= i;` es igual a `factorial=factorial*1;`

3- si le asignas 3 a la variable `numero`, lo que sucederá en el bucle es lo siguiente

```
cuando i=1 factorial=factorial*i; --> factorial=1*1 --->factorial=1
cuando i=2 factorial=factorial*i; --> factorial=1*2 --->factorial=2
cuando i=3 factorial=factorial*i; --> factorial=2*3 --->factorial=6
```

dependiendo del editor o IDE que usas para copilar tu código, debes aprender a usar la herramienta `debug` ,la cual te ayudara bastante en dudas que puedas tener sobre el funcionamiento de tu codigo